# Oracle Apex column value conditional display

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I used the query below in interactive report and turned escape special characters off. This is just coloring text whereas requirement is to highlight entire row.

Any suggestions?

Ex:

```
SELECT "P_IT_ISSUES"."ISSUE_SUMMARY" as "ISSUE_SUMMARY",
    decode("P_IT_PEOPLE_1"."PERSON_NAME",NULL,'Unassigned',
        "P_IT_PEOPLE_1"."PERSON_NAME") 
        as "ASSIGNED_TO",
        case when "P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS" ='Open' 
        then '<aaab style= "    color: green; " >'
        ||"P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS"||'</aaab>'
        when  "P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS" ='On-Hold' 
        then '<aaab style= "    color: red; " >'
        ||"P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS"||'</aaab>' 
        else '<aaab style= "    color: red; " >'
        ||"P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS"||'</aaab>' 
        end "Status"
FROM "P_IT_PEOPLE" "P_IT_PEOPLE_1",
    "P_IT_DEPARTMENTS" "P_IT_DEPARTMENTS",
    "P_IT_PEOPLE" "P_IT_PEOPLE",
    "P_IT_ISSUES" "P_IT_ISSUES"
WHERE "P_IT_ISSUES"."IDENTIFIED_BY_PERSON_ID"="P_IT_PEOPLE"."PERSON_ID"
AND "P_IT_ISSUES"."ASSIGNED_TO_PERSON_ID"="P_IT_PEOPLE_1"."PERSON_ID"(+)
AND "P_IT_ISSUES"."RELATED_DEPT_ID"="P_IT_DEPARTMENTS"."DEPT_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to do a revised version of this post
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/06/highlight-cell-background-in-apex-report.html

To highlight the entire cell/row, you need to apply a conditional class to your column, similar to how you're doing now - but could be a simple value.

First, add a hidden column to your query.

```
case when status = 'X' then 'foo' else 'bar' end my_class
```

which you would add as HTML expression of a visible column, eg: the status column.

```
<span class="#MY_CLASS#">#STATUS#</span>
```

Then have an after-refresh dynamic action with JS, ensuring 'fire in initialisation' is checked.
This JS looks for any elements with that class, then climbs the DOM to find the relevant cell/row, and applies a colour to the row.

```
$("#my_report_static_id .foo").each(function(){
 $(this).closest('tr').css({"background-color":"red"});
});
```

You could parameterise that colour, if necessary, using similar techniques.

Comment: do you mean add the new column as it is in the query? what does status='X' indicate? could you please clarify bit more?

Comment: Yes, adding to your query, next to all the other columns. Status = 'X' as in whatever your condition is. In your case, something like i.status = 'Open'