# Query for interactive report failing with highlight row css conditions

Tags: css, oracle, oracle-apex

I am using query below to highlight status column on basis of column values.
its failing with error in else block:
ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query!

ORA-06550: line 12, column 15: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Where is it going wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `CASE` (which selects status) causes problems, because

- it ends with a comma and there's nothing after it
- you named the whole CASE construct as `"PT_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS"` which is a column name; you should use **alias**, e.g. simply `status`

Something like this:

```
SELECT "P_IT_ISSUES"."ISSUE_SUMMARY" AS "ISSUE_SUMMARY",
       "P_IT_PEOPLE"."PERSON_NAME" AS "IDENTIFIED_BY",
       "P_IT_ISSUES"."IDENTIFIED_DATE" AS "IDENTIFIED_DATE",
       "P_IT_DEPARTMENTS"."DEPT_NAME" AS "DEPT_NAME",
       DECODE ("P_IT_PEOPLE_1"."PERSON_NAME",
               NULL, 'Unassigned',
               "P_IT_PEOPLE_1"."PERSON_NAME")
          AS "ASSIGNED_TO",
       CASE
          WHEN "P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS" = 'Open'
          THEN
                '<aaab style= "    color: green; " >'
             || TO_CHAR ("P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS", '999,999,999,999,999')
             || '</aaab>'
          WHEN "P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS" = 'On-Hold'
          THEN
                '<aaab style= "    color: red; " >'
             || TO_CHAR ("P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS", '999,999,999,999,999')
             || '</aaab>'
          ELSE
                '<aaab style= "    color: red; " >'
             || TO_CHAR ("P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS", '999,999,999,999,999')
             || '</aaab>'
       END AS status                                                   -> this!
  FROM "P_IT_PEOPLE" "P_IT_PEOPLE_1",
       "P_IT_DEPARTMENTS" "P_IT_DEPARTMENTS",
       "P_IT_PEOPLE" "P_IT_PEOPLE",
       "P_IT_ISSUES" "P_IT_ISSUES"
 WHERE     "P_IT_ISSUES"."IDENTIFIED_BY_PERSON_ID" =
              "P_IT_PEOPLE"."PERSON_ID"
       AND "P_IT_ISSUES"."ASSIGNED_TO_PERSON_ID" =
              "P_IT_PEOPLE_1"."PERSON_ID"(+)
       AND "P_IT_ISSUES"."RELATED_DEPT_ID" = "P_IT_DEPARTMENTS"."DEPT_ID"
```

---

**However**, I'd further rewrite that code and

- omit double quotes when referencing tables and columns
- use proper (read: simpler) table aliases
- remove unnecessary column aliases
- rewrite FROM clause and explicitly join tables

Something like this:

```
SELECT i.issue_summary,
       b.person_name AS identified_by,
       i.identified_date,
       d.dept_name,
       DECODE (a.person_name, NULL, 'Unassigned', a.person_name)
          AS assigned_to,
       CASE
          WHEN i.status = 'Open'
          THEN
                '<aaab style= "    color: green; " >'
             || TO_CHAR (i.status, '999,999,999,999,999')
             || '</aaab>'
          WHEN i.status = 'On-Hold'
          THEN
                '<aaab style= "    color: red; " >'
             || TO_CHAR (i.status, '999,999,999,999,999')
             || '</aaab>'
          ELSE
                '<aaab style= "    color: red; " >'
             || TO_CHAR (i.status, '999,999,999,999,999')
             || '</aaab>'
       END
          AS status
  FROM p_it_issues i
       JOIN p_it_departments d ON i.related_dept_id = d.dept_id
       JOIN p_i_people b ON i.identified_by_person_id = b.person_id
       LEFT JOIN p_it_people a ON a.person_id = i.assigned_to_person_id;
```

Isn't that simpler and easier to read & maintain?

Comment: Thanks, now the problem is i want to highlight the row, but it is just coloring the text. that too if Status ='Closed', color coming red as default condition. The row with status as open has no color/highlight.So,1: i wanted to highlight the entire row accordingly. 2: It is coloring text that too of just one value. i cannot attach screenshot in comments ele would have shown. ANy advise?

Comment: I'm not good at CSS, sorry. Problem stated was **ORA-00923** which is now, I presume, fixed. I'd suggest you to open another question which is related to "how to highlight the whole row using CSS?".

Comment: i have already opened it but no answers yet-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505073/oracle-apex-column-value-conditional-display

Comment: I see; hopefully, someone will be able to assist.

Answer (score 1):

The final line of the case statement was invalid.

```
    case when "P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS" ='Open' 
    then '<aaab style= "    color: green; " >'
    ||to_char("P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS",'999,999,999,999,999')||'</aaab>'
    when  "P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS" ='On-Hold' 
    then '<aaab style= "    color: red; " >'
    ||to_char("P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS",'999,999,999,999,999')||'</aaab>' 
    else '<aaab style= "    color: blue; " >'
    ||to_char("P_IT_ISSUES"."STATUS",'999,999,999,999,999')||'</aaab>' 
    end  as "Status",
```

You may also find your code easier to read if you don't double quote identifiers, and use simpler table aliases, but I realise this code may be generated from somewhere.